# How do I reference the correct cell on a Data Grid View that has been sorted?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a WinForms application that has some data in a DataGridView. If a user double clicks on a cell then that row needs to be removed, and that works fine unless they click on a column first to sort the data by that column. If it has been sorted then the row index of the event still refers to the origional value in that row (I.E. Double clicking on the first item after sorting the data will remove the row that was at the top before the sort).

Is there a way for me to update the row indexes when the sort occurs?

Current initialize is similar to:

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
 da.Fill(dt);
 this.dgv1.DataSource = dt;
```

And the double click event is similar to:

```
private void dgv1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)dgv1.DataSource;

    if (e.RowIndex > -1)
    {
        dt.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
    }
}
```

I suspect the issue is something very simple that I am not seeing right now..

Comment: Post your code for sorting the grid.

Comment: Why not remove the `DataGridViewRow` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the property `DataBoundItem` of a `DataGridViewRow` to reference to the underlying `DataRow` and use the `Remove` method instead:

```
private void dgv1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){
   DataTable dt = (DataTable)dgv1.DataSource;    
   if(e.RowIndex>-1)
      dt.Rows.Remove(((DataRowView)dgv1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).Row);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. Removing the DataGridViewRow seemed to cause a bug at another place in the code.